# Losing conditional formatting on some sheets in workbook, not others

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm adding some conditional formatting to each sheet on an excel file. When I publish to the server and download it from there, some sheets lose their conditional formatting, but others keep it. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: What if you don't save it to a server, and download it again? Perhaps email to yourself, or put on some other network, then see if it's still there. It may be getting cut out when saving?

Comment: I should've started with this issue instead of the other one, as that was a work-around for this issue. The CF is definitely there on my local copy of the file, but is getting lost when it goes to the server (on certain pages), and my workaround was to add CF to the excel writing code. Which nearly worked except for the error box. I still haven't resolved either issue, and I'm at a bit of a dead end because I don't think we can update to the latest version of Spreadsheetgear on our current license.

Comment: I've saved and reopened the file locally many times. The CF is still there. It's only when I download it from the server again that the CF gets lost. The only thing I can think of is that there might be something in the code that clears the CF but I've looked over it many times and can't find anything. It's even getting lost on some pages that aren't populated in the code so I'm doubting that too. This question is really more of a Hail Mary than anything...